# How can I echo data about each item from inside of a function?

Tags: php, html, arrays, loops, foreach

Okay. Lower your n00b standards for this one. Turn back now.

I have three files:

- **index.php** (home page)
- **project.php** (template page for each project)
- **project-data.php** (which holds the project data for both Index and Project)

I have a function with a list of projects.

**project-data.php**

```
<?php

function getDataForPageRender($id)
{

  if (empty($home)) {
    $id = $_GET["id"];
  }

  $returnArray = array();
  if($id == 1)
  {  
    $returnArray['title'] = 'Project Snoop';
  } else if($id == 2)
  {  
    $returnArray['title'] = 'Project Biggie';
  } else if($id ==3)
  {  
    $returnArray['title'] = 'Project Tupac';
  }
    return $returnArray;
}
?>
```

(There's actually about 25 projects, not just three. Thus my urge to automate this stuff. But not enough projects to make me want to create a database, with my current level of knowledge.)

And here's my project page for each one, which is working wonderfully. The URLs for each project are formatted as "project.php?id=3".

**project.php**

```
<?php
include 'project-data.php';
$dataForPage = getDataForPageRender($id);
$id = $_GET["id"];
$title = $dataForPage['title'];
?>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
  <h1><?php echo $title; ?></h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Now, on my index.php page, I'd like to echo each project title. Like this:

---

Project Snoop

Project Biggie

Project Tupac

---

I've tried a foreach loop in a countless number of ways, to no avail.

**index.php**

```
<?php
include 'project-data.php';
foreach (array(1,2,3) as &$value) {

  $home = "true"; // I know, ghetto. I'm trying lots of different things quickly.
  $id = $value;
  getDataForPageRender();
  $dataForPage = getDataForPageRender($id);
  echo $dataForPage['title'];
  echo "<br>";
}
?>
```

I can't seem to echo the title for each project on index.php. This seems so simple, but each page refresh brings frustration to my soul.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: If you look at your function here `getDataForPageRender($id)`, you will see that it takes an `$id` parameter and returns an `array`. Hope this hints helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `$home` in `project-data.php` which may exist in `index.php`, but does not exist within the function `getDataForPageRender`.

You'll need to follow DI and pass `$home` along into the function such as this:

```
function getDataForPageRender($id, $home) //<-- added home
{

  if (empty($home)) {
    $id = $_GET["id"];
  }

 /* rest of code */
```

Then, you need to pass `$home` to your function.

```
$dataForPage = getDataForPageRender($id, $home); //which you set as $home = "true";
```

That should get your code running, but I'd like to point out somethings that might cause a warning but you might have warnings disabled.

```
foreach (array(1,2,3) as &$value) {
```

`&$value`, the & is pass by reference, but since the array is anonymous, there's no way you can change the values of that array, just leave it at `foreach (array(1,2,3) as $value) {`, without the `&`.

And I have no idea why you're running `getDataForPageRender();` without any parameters.

Comment: I was running it without parameters because that was just one of the code iterations I tried (EDIT: what I was trying at first wasn't *as* bad as what I have here, so I should've just posted that). I was thinking about posting a bunch of those iterations on here but thought it might clutter things, because they were all fails. Thanks for the answer, I'm trying it out now!

Comment: Actually, testing `$home` and setting `$id` is probably best done outside the function. Then you just need to pass in the correct `$id`. Try to encapsulate the function such that you have all data going in through arguments and coming out as return values. Fewer side effects means fewer bugs.

Comment: @dave, passing $home to the function--Of course. It works! And thanks for the &$value -> $value tip. I had misinterpreted a tutorial. Many thanks, dude! :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why you don't wanna use a DB on this one, but you can initialize an array of default values like this:

```
function getDataForPageRender($id = null) {

    $default_values = array(
        1 => array('title' => 'Project Snoop'),
        2 => array('title' => 'Project Biggie'),
        3 => array('title' => 'Project Tupac'),
    );
    // either you pass an id which gives a specific entry, or show all results
    return isset($default_values[$id]) ? $default_values[$id] : $default_values;
}
```

So in `project.php?id=3`:

```
<?php
include 'project-data.php';
$id = $_GET["id"]; // this comes first
$dataForPage = getDataForPageRender($id); // set an ID to get specific entry
$title = $dataForPage['title'];
?>

<html>
<head></head>
<body>
  <h1><?php echo $title; ?></h1>
</body>
</html>
```

In `index.php`:

```
<?php
$dataForPage = getDataForPageRender(null); // just pass a null, or an empty argument is also okay
foreach($dataForPage as $id => $values) {
    echo '<h1>' . $values['title'] . '</h1><br/>';
}
?>
```

Comment: Cool, this looks like a cleaner solution than what I was using! In my "real" code (I anonymized/simplified it here), I actually have more data for each project (i.e., "Subtitle", "Summary", etc.) so I'll figure out how to add that info to the array. I'm not using a database because I was told that it was faster just to include the data in the files here instead of retrieving from a database. Thanks for the info @ghost!

Comment: @AnnaBlabber of course you could just build up on this code, you could just separate those default values outside and do it your way. there are pros and cons of course, if you're going to reach thousands of entries it might be feasible to use tables on this one, but if its just hundreds, then arrays will do just fine. im glad this helped

Answer (score 1):

@AnnaBlabber , I would like to recommend you to use Object oriented approach

- Create a class called as `Project`
- Declare a properties like project id, title etc.
- Declare an array holding instances of the `Project` class.

Later you can iterate over the array, render the link using the element retrieved. For more information about knowing basics of classes, you can visit [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php).
This will surely help you to get rid of if/else structure as well as it will make your code cleaner.